# How do i change the values of cloned elements on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

i set an onchange function to a select input in a table row,
i cloned and appended the row onclick of a button. The clones aren't responding to the onchange function being set. Here's the code so far

```js
<!-- clone and append function-->

$("button").click(function() {
  var clone = $('#item_row').clone();
  $('#item_row').after(clone)    
});    

$('#quantity').change(function() {
  $('.price').text($('.price').val() * $(this).val())
})
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr id="item_row">
          <td>
            <select id="quantity">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p class="price">20,000</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
    <button>Fetch Row</button>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems.

First use .on such as

```
$(document).on('click', '. quantity', function () {
    // do stuff here
});
```

Second, how would the js know which quantity select you are changing since there is no unique identifier?  You'll have to add one using rel="unique_id" and keep a running counting to add to the cloned rows.

Third, don't use ID="quantity" make it a class as you'll have more than one

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

Your quantity calculation was wrong, a `<p>` has no "value". Also use event delegation for the cloned selects, otherwise they won't be recognized.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
 var clone = $('#item_row').clone();
    $('#item_row').after(clone)
});

$(document).on('change', '.quantity', function() {
 $('.price').text(parseInt($('.price').text()) * $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
            <tr id="item_row">
                    <td>
                        <select class="quantity">
                               <option>1</option>
                               <option>2</option>
                               <option>3</option>     
                        </select>                                                                     
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="price">20,000</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <button>Fetch Row</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Selector of change event  do with `class` instead of `id` .Id is unique for whole document .For dynamically created element click use with [`on()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZl9Xmp4bVAhVBp48KHb9BAzcQFggsMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fon%2F&usg=AFQjCNFJf1Y9q7iSptlkW-9S_Ki4f0hD8w)

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var clone = $('#item_row').clone();
  $('#item_row').after(clone)

});


$(document).on('change','.quantity',function() {
  $('.price').text($('.price').val() * $(this).val())
  console.log('changed')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr id="item_row">
      <td>
        <select id="quantity" class="quantity">
                               <option>1</option>
                               <option>2</option>
                               <option>3</option>     
                        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="price">20,000</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<button>Fetch Row</button>
```